# How to combine rewrites with different roots in location blocks

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, php

I'm struggling to understand how to control rewrites to PHP scripts when the location blocks that do the rewrites require different roots.

Here's the simplified example. My catch-all front controller must be in the web root, but the firewall.php script must not be.

The purpose of this is to provide gated access to download files not under the root.

```
server {

    # Requests for media forced through firewall script outside web root
    # /path/to/secure-area/firewall.php
    #
    location ^~ /downloads/ {
       root /path/to/secure-area;
       rewrite ^/.+$ /firewall.php last;
    }

    # Regular requests bootstrap front controller under web-root
    # /path/to/web-root/index.php;
    #
    location / {
        root /path/to/web-root;
        index index.php
        if ( -e $request_filename ) {
            break;
        }
        rewrite ^.+$ /index.php last;
    }

    # Execute PHP via php-fpm
    # rewrites hitting this are not mapping request_filename properly
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
       if ( !-f $request_filename ) {
         return 404;
       }
       include /usr/local/nginx/conf/fastcgi_params;
       fastcgi_pass   unix:/tmp/php.sock;
       fastcgi_index  index.php;
    }
}
```

The obvious solution is having a common root, but this is not possible in my situation. I cannot place the secure location under the web root and the web root must stay as-is.

It looks as if the `root` directive is only effective within the location block that defines it. The rewrites are individually working fine, but when the `~ \.php` block is hit, the root is lost.

I'm obviously doing it wrong, so how should I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Untested, but something like this ought to help you. It uses the http://wiki.nginx.org/XSendfile to serve the protected content from a different root. Also uses try_files which is a much better pattern for Front Controllers.

```
    server {

    # More here: http://wiki.nginx.org/XSendfile
    #
    # To serve /downloads/some.zip
    # get php to set the http header:
    #
    # X-Accel-Redirect: /downloads/some.zip
    #
    # and then the file /path/to/secure-area/downloads/some.zip
    # will be sent by nginx
    location /downloads/ {
      internal;
      root   /path/to/secure-area;
    }        

    location / {
        root /path/to/web-root;
        index index.php
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }

    # make sure you read http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls
    location ~* \.php$ {
      try_files $uri =404;
      fastcgi_pass   unix:/tmp/php.sock;
      fastcgi_index  index.php;
      include /usr/local/nginx/conf/fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the try_files tip. I'll look at that. I wish I could use X-Send, but I can't for two reasons. (1) the site must be deployed to Apache too, and won't always have an equivalent module. (2) The PHP script that sends the X- headers can't be under the web root either. (codebase overlap)

Comment: Ah, you could probably easily fix the nginx side of things to send the X-Accel-Redirect from outside the webroot. Haven't touched an Apache config for years though :P

Comment: Sending the header from outside the root is essentially the question I'm asking. I've sorted it using an `alias` but means duplicating the fastcgi stuff.

Comment: In your example, the php-fm section handles the regular content, and the firewall.php which sits in a different root folder handles the authentication? And essentially they're two different php apps? What does the Apache config look like? Can you post that in your question too?

Comment: I haven't tackled the apache config yet. I will accept your answer if no more are added, then I'll post the solution I ended up with. By coincidence something just came up that X-Send will be great for, so that's awesome news to me.